# What kind of bb is this?

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

not sure what kind of bb mount this is for a crank? It’s like this on both sides[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably ISIS splined. That’s the only one with splines of that length with the smooth end.

https://www.sheldonbrown.com/bbsize.html